# Integer Value to Color (JAVA)

Tags: java, arrays, colors, assign

I made an 2D Array filled randomly with numbers between 0 and a number selected by the user (max 6). I would like to change those numbers with colors, but when I try to assign each value to a color I get the message that I cannot convert from int to color... Any recomendation? because I'm really stuck

```
    public static void rellenarTablero(int[][] tablero) {
    System.out.println("Introduzca el numero de colores (de 2 a 6): ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int colores = in.nextInt();
    while(colores<2||colores>6){
        System.out.println("Elija un numero valido:");
        colores = in.nextInt();
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < tablero.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < tablero[x].length; y++) {
            tablero[x][y] =1+(int)(Math.random()*(colores));
            if(x==1){
                x=Color.BLUE;
            }if(y==1){
                y=Color.BLUE;
            }
            if(x==2){
                x=Color.RED;
            } 
            if(y==2){
                y=Color.RED;
            }
            if(x==3){
                x=Color.GREEN;
            }
            if(y==3){
                y=Color.GREEN;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How should those numbers be translated to colors? For example, if a user enters 3, then what color should that result in?

Comment: You can start with a `Map<Integer, Color>` map ...

Comment: well, the assignment is irrelevant, let's put 1=blue, 2=red & 3=green for this example, and the code is in the edit, sorry

Comment: I'm very confused on the functionality here. If you define `x` as type `int` you can not then assign it type `Color`.

Comment: So must I define `x` as `color` instead `int` type? Then How could I fill my Array randomly? Sorry if is an stupid question but i'm just a beginner

Comment: I'm guessing you want to fill `tablero` with randomly chosen `Color`s.  If that's true, then `tablero` must be declared as a 2D array of `Color`, not of `int`

Comment: yes that is, but if I declare `tablero` as `Color [][]` I don't know how to fill it, because `Math.random()` gives me a `double` and I can´t convert it to `color` type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should fix your code. I have inserted comments about the most important changes I made.

```
// if the table is to be filled with colors, declare it an table of Color
public static void rellenarTablero(Color[][] tablero) {
    System.out.println("Introduzca el numero de colores (de 2 a 6): ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int colores = in.nextInt();
    while (colores < 2 || colores > 6) {
        System.out.println("Elija un numero valido:");
        colores = in.nextInt();
    }
    // I prefer to use a Random object for random integers, it’s a matter of taste
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int x = 0; x < tablero.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < tablero[x].length; y++) {
            int numeroAleatorioDeColor = 1 + rand.nextInt(3);
            // prefer if-else to make sure exactly one case is chosen
            if (numeroAleatorioDeColor == 1) {
                // fill the color into the table (not the int)
                tablero[x][y] = Color.BLUE;
            }
            else if (numeroAleatorioDeColor == 2) {
                tablero[x][y] = Color.RED;
            }
            else if (numeroAleatorioDeColor == 3) {
                tablero[x][y] = Color.GREEN;
            }
            else {
                System.err.println("Error interno " + numeroAleatorioDeColor);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It may be easier to put all the colors you have to choose from into a separate array from the start:

```
static final Color[] todosColores = { Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW, Color.BLACK, Color.ORANGE };
```

This is especially true if you have many colors to choose from. Now you can do just:

```
            // number to use for array index; should start from 0, so don’t add 1
            int numeroAleatorioDeColor = rand.nextInt(todosColores.length);
            tablero[x][y] = todosColores[numeroAleatorioDeColor];
```